# Encounter the error req#logout requires a callback function while using req.logout() in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Im new to the express and passport. req.logout() function is used in my project was working fine previously. recently i have updated express and passport versions into "4.18.2" and "0.6.0" respectively. Now I am getting an error "req#logout requires a callback function" i was trying so many things and still I couldn't figure it out.

below are my js file code snipits after I adding a call back function as the version change of passport and express.

```
import express, { Router, Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

import passport, { FailedAuthError, samlStrategy } from '../auth';

export const destroySession = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    return req.session.destroy((err: Error) => {
        if (err) log.error(`[logoutHandler] Error while logging out user:\n${err}`);

        req.logout((err: Error) => {
            if (err) log.error(`[logoutHandler] Error inside req.logout:\n${err}`);
            res.redirect(LOGIN_PATH);
          });
    });
}
```

after adding this rolleback function into logout, now i'm getting a build failur

```
src/controllers/auth.ts(169,20): error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! wma-authentication@1.0.0 build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the wma-authentication@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tdebuild/.npm/_logs/2023-08-01T12_11_58_516Z-debug.log
```